# Unit testing Angular controller using capture variable for 'this' with controllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I've been following [this Angular style guide by John Pappa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#testing), and I've been having problems testing with the controllerAs syntax. Specifically the guide says to use a capture variable like so `var vm = this;` to avoid attaching things to $scope inside the controller.

My issue comes when I start to test controllers using this capture variable. When I create a controller in my unit test, I am not able to call methods attached to the capture variable.

My code is as follows:

Controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc function
     * @name mytodoApp.controller:MainCtrl
     * @description
     * # MainCtrl
     * Controller of the mytodoApp
     */
    angular.module('mytodoApp')
        .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var vm = this;

            vm.tasks = [];

            vm.addTask = addTask;
            vm.removeTask = removeTask;

            function addTask() {
                if(!contains(vm.tasks, $scope.task)){
                    vm.tasks.push($scope.task);
                } else {
                    vm.isInvalid = true;
                }

                $scope.task = '';
            };

            function removeTask(index) {
                vm.tasks.splice(index, 1);
            };

            var contains = function(list, item) {
                var res = list.indexOf(item);
                return res === -1 ? false : true;
            };
        });
})();
```

Unit Test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('mytodoApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
      // place here mocked dependencies
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of tasks to the viewmodel', function () {
    expect(MainCtrl.tasks.length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('should add items to the list', function() {
    scope.task = 'example task';
    MainCtrl.addTodo();
    expect(MainCtrl.tasks.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl should add items to the list FAILED
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'MainCtrl.addTodo()')
      at /Users/kyle/Code/AngularProjects/mytodo/test/spec/controllers/main.js:28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `addTodo()` function in your `MainCtrl`. Did you mean to run `addTask()`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. The test passes now.